# Config logstash for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have installed logstash-elasticsearch-kibana on the local. Now I want to config logstash to push data into elasticsearch, there codes below are the same with tutorial in guide on the Elastic page. But I can't run the config file successful. Excepted one time but I don't know why and then I try to test again but fail anyway

This is first-pipeline.conf

```
input {
    file {
        path => "D:/grok.log"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}
filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "localhost"
        port => "9200"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

This is grok.log

```
83.149.9.216 - - [04/Jan/2015:05:13:42 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-  monitorama-2013/images/kibana-search.png
HTTP/1.1" 200 203023 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36"
```

All the configs are the same with the tutorial but they can't run

**Edit 1**

I think there are somethings wrong with the filter or output but I don't know where-it-is, cuz I've just tried tutorial as the guide only.
And I got message "Logstash startup completed"
So I think that my config is right but I can't see my data in elasticsearch

Comment: What error are you getting in your output? Try running logstash with the `--debug` to get more insights.

Comment: actually logstash runs without any error but the data in log file does not exist in elasticsearch. 
btw, does logstash have any config to print out the result after processing the data through the component ?

Comment: You can test the configuration file using this command:-
logstash agent -f config --configtest (going into bin folder)

Comment: Yes, I have tested and gotten message "Configuration OK"

Comment: You said that logstash runs without an error but do you see any results in stdout? I would recommend to set `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` in your file input to avoid sincedb issues.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to define node.
I recommend to use transport protocol.
About Your problem. Probobly it is getting there
When accessing kibana be sure to define proper index pattern. 
If it went once it should go all the time ( or there are no changes in the log so it will not do anything )
Try to debug it see logs of logstash and elasticsearch and share them with us. 
If You are not sure of the filter just remove it.

Comment: if compare with tutorial, my config is not wrong. But I don't know why I got nothing in elasticsearch